# Summing the first variable in each element in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, element

I'm trying to sum the first item in each element of a list.

I've tried printing the variable sum to see what's going on and it seems to give a list of the correct elements.

Here's my code:

````
def define_elements(points):
    for sublist in points:
        sum = 0 
        sum += sublist[0]
    return sum

print(define_elements(datapoints) ```

When I run the following code it prints -1. I'm looking for an answer of 10.
````

Comment: define `sum` outside for loop and sum shoud be `8` not `10`

Comment: decalre outside `sum = 0 ` loop ; dont use it as variable it is a builtin function

Answer (score 2):

- [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) - Takes an iterable and returns the sum of items in it. it only works with numerical values, trying to use it with non-numeric type will result in an error.

[more details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

---

```
datapoints = [(1, 1), (3, 3), (5, 5), (-1, -1)]
total = sum(i[0] for i in datapoints)
print(total)
```

**O/P:**

```
 8
```

or suggested by  Gábor Fekete

```
total = sum(list(zip(*datapoints))[0])
```

Comment: no need for brackets `sum(i[0] for i in datapoints)`

Comment: `total = sum(list(zip(*datapoints))[0])` is another approach, make two tuples of the 2-element tuples, the first one contains the first elements and you just sum them. This is only good for smaller lists as this creates a list. bharatk's solution uses generator expression which is better for large amount of data.

Comment: @ Gábor Fekete thanks for an added new approach sum of the first variable in each element in a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def define_elements(points):        
    return sum(map(lambda x:x[0], points))
```